# Nginx: Deny scripts from running in a directory as well as all its subdirectories

Tags: nginx

Say my website allows users to create directories as well as upload to a directory called "/uploads", like so:

/uploads/user_created_folder_1

/uploads/user_created_folder_2

/uploads/user_created_folder_3

... so on and so forth

How do I prevent any potentially malicious script from being executed in "/uploads" as well as **all of its subdirectories**?

Is the following code in the server block correct?

```
location /uploads/.*.(php|pl|py|jsp|asp|sh|cgi)$ {
                return 403;
                error_page 403 403.html;
        }
```

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, nginx does not execute scripts. Under some conditions it could proxy request to other server that execute script. Most commonly condition is *extension* of file in request and typical nginx config block looks like this:

```
location ~* \.php$ {
  fastcgi_pass backend;
  ...
}
```

So your question should be: how to prevent proxying requests to folder `/uploads/`? And with this typical config answer is as simple as:

```
location ^~ /uploads/ {
}
```

which means: if request to folder uploads, just serve them as static files, do not try to look for regexp locations for them (that require you to understand different types of nginx [`location`s](http://nginx.org/r/location)).

If your config is much different from typical one, we need to see it to give you proper answer.

Comment: Thank you @alexeyten. Should the code (location ^~ /uploads/ {
}) be placed before or after the fastcgi block of code? Or does it not matter? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't matter. Nginx checks prefix locations before regexp's ones.

Comment: Works, thanks @alexeyten! I tested by uploading a php file onto the folder, and requested for it. Nginx serves it as a static file, which causes the browser to download it. That's the expected behaviour yes?

Comment: Yes, that's default behavior.